# How to crawl specific ASP.NET pages using Python?

Tags: python, asp.net, web-crawler

I want to crawl an ASP.NET website but the urls are all the same how can I crawl specific pages using python?

**here is the website I want to crawl:** 
http://www.fveconstruction.ch/index.htm

(I am using beautifulsoup, urllib and python 3)

What information should I get to distinguish a page from the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the target website is just a single page application, it can't be crawled. As a workaround you can see the requests (GET, POST etc) that actually go when you manually navigate through the website and ask the crawler to use those. Or, teach your crawler to execute javascript at least what's on the target website.

It's the website who need to change to be easily crawlable, they need to provide a reasonable non-AJAX version of every page that needs to be indexed, or links to a page that needs to be indexed. Or use something like what pushState does in angularJs.